# matplotlib.pyplot How to name different lines in the same plot?

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib, diagram

Think about doing this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x_A,y_A,'g--')
plt.plot(x_B,y_B,'r-o')
plt.show()
```

How would you go about giving both lines different names, i.e. like Microsoft Excel would do it?

Comment: Another approach is to place the labels near the lines that they correspond to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29724863/1959808

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x_A,y_A,'g--', label="plot A")
plt.plot(x_B,y_B,'r-o', label="plot A")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can give each line a label.

```
plt.plot(x_A,y_A,'g--', label='x_A')
```

These labels can then be displayed in a legend with

```
legend()
```

`legend` takes some arguments, see the documentation to see what it can do.