# How to properly plot labels in a graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to plot a 'Sequence of function' in Python with the corresponding label for function inside the plot.

I use matplotlib, however, I am facing the below issues.

> (1). The graph should label $f_n$ corresponding to each function.

> (2). It must save to a file with the labels included.

Here is my code :

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc('text', usetex = True) #for LaTex notation in the Plot
mpl.rc('font', family = 'serif')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.style.use(['ggplot','dark_background'])

x=np.arange(-1,1,0.001)

for i in range(1,5,1):
    y = 1 - (1 / (1+x**2)**i)
    plt.plot(x,y,label=i)

plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$y$')

plt.savefig('seqn_of_function1.eps', format='eps', 
dpi=1000)

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

The problem with this code is :

> 1. This code gives the following output but cannot save the **.eps** file with the labels (`plt.savefig('seqn_of_function1.eps', format='eps',  dpi=1000)`)
>    [image]

> 2. It only labels 'i', however, I want it to label as $f_i$.

I changed the line in my code as : `plt.plot(x,y,label='$f_$',i)` but it gives an "invalid_syntax" error.

Comment: Have you tried using `plt.plot(x,y,label='f_{}'.format(i))`? (Instead of `plt.plot(x,y,label='$f_$',i)`)

Comment: @bene....this gives an error.

Comment: also how to save the .eps file with the labels? My code doesn't do that....

Comment: I'm looking into it. The labels won't be saved because you save the figure before you create the labes (`plt.legend()`) -> first calls `plt.legend()` and then `plt.savefig(...)`

Comment: @bene...Thank you so much....it fixed.....well what about the previous problem..??to create label with $f_n$

Comment: Using  `plt.plot(x, y, label='$f_{}$'.format(i))` works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)  # for LaTex notation in the Plot
mpl.rc('font', family='serif')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.style.use(['ggplot', 'dark_background'])

x = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.001)

for i in range(1, 5, 1):
    y = 1 - (1 / (1 + x ** 2) ** i)
    plt.plot(x, y, label='$f_{}$'.format(i))

plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$y$')

plt.legend()

plt.savefig('seqn_of_function1.eps', format='eps', dpi=1000)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot....Can you tell me how to create the label on each functions rather on a side of the plot....??

Comment: Sorry, no.. . But you can check the docu: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

Comment: Maybe this is a help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992038/inline-labels-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

you can use fString to display your labels as follow:

```
plt.plot(x, y, label=f'$f_{i}$')
```

which value of *i* changes during run-time