# Putting text inside plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am making multiple line plots. In each step I add another line to the previous plot. They look like this:

[image]

Now I want to delete legend and add names of the countries above the lines, for instance China above blue line. How can I add a text by the lines?

My code for creating those multiple plots:

```
for i in years:
    yearsi=list((range(1960,i+1)))
    yearsi=map(str,yearsi)
    ax=df.pivot_table(values=yearsi, columns='Country Name').plot()
    ax.set_ylim([0, 1500])
    ax.set_xticks(range(0,61,10))
    ax.set_xticklabels(range(1960, 2021,10))
```

Where dataframe is like this

[image]

Comment: There is a way to add text directly to the plot at some specified location. Have you tried this? https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/gallery/pyplots/pyplot_text.html

Comment: yes, I tried but was not getting desired result, I think my mistake must be with coordinates, I was setting them as y= df[str(years)]  and x equal to some integer

Comment: Related [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992038/inline-labels-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tested it out quickly and you should be able to achieve what you're looking for using `Text` if you get your coordinates right.

Create a new text instance:

```
self.look_at_me = self.ax2.text(0, 0, 'Look at me!', size=12, color='g')
```

**The above is all you should need for your example!** The 0, 0 are the x, y coordinates for the text.

Now I have a function which is animating a plot, you might not have this.
Anyway just for something extra you can update the position of the text to some new x and y coordinates based on the data. i.e.

```
def animate(i):
    self.look_at_me.set_position((self.df['t'][i], self.df['r_mag'][i]))
```

That gives the following result and it should work with as many text labels as you need with the corresponding data.

[image]