# Positioning a text outside the graph in accordance to the graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Hello I am trying to place a text right outside the graph where `y = -100` is. The thing is the graph y and x values always change depending on the different numbers inputted within the code. A purple line is drawn at y= -100.

```
#Tittle, ylable, xlable 
plt.title('PnL in Accordense to Number of Trades', fontdict={'fontsize': 12})
plt.ylabel('PnL of the asset')
plt.xlabel('Number of trades')

#Plotting the PnL, Max_profit, Max_drawdown
PnL = plt.bar(x_indexes,bar_positions,width =width_bar, label= 'PnL')
Maximum_Profits = plt.bar(x_indexes+width_bar,Max_profit,width =width_bar, label= 'Max Upside', color ='green')
Maximum_Drawdown = plt.bar(x_indexes+width_bar*2,Max_drawdown,width =width_bar, label= 'Max Drawdown', color='red')
plt.axhline(-100, color = 'purple', linewidth =1.4, linestyle='--')
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want the labels to occur at the purple line?

Comment: @DavidErickson yes I want the label to be at the purple line but outside of the graph much like the y-ticks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add labels outside the plotting area, it would be far easier to add a legend for the line to the graph. If you want it to be inline, there is an interesting workaround posted here: [Inline labels in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992038/inline-labels-in-matplotlib)

Comment: You can use `plt.gcf()` to place a text outside the graphs