# Is there a better way to align these labels with the lines in this plot I created using matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

This is the code I have and so far the output is good but I think I can modify the label of lines "1-2", ..."8-1" better. Is there a way to make them more fitted to each part of the line?
I found a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992038/inline-labels-in-matplotlib) but it's a code that gives labels for every new line but mine has a continuous line with different points

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("data.txt",sep='[\t,]', engine='python')
print(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data.plot(x="Eastings", y="Northings", ax=ax, color = "violet", legend=None)
ax.plot(data.iloc[[0, -1]]['Eastings'], data.iloc[[0, -1]]['Northings'], color='violet')
data.plot.scatter(x="Eastings", y="Northings", ax=ax, color ="purple")

station_list = data["Station"].values.tolist()
x = data["Eastings"].values.tolist()
y = data["Northings"].values.tolist()

stat_lines = [] #making line labels such as "1-2", "2-3" ... "8-1"
for l in range(1,len(station_list)+1):
    if l == (len(station_list)):
        line = str(l) + '-' +str(l-(len(station_list)-1))
        stat_lines.append(line)
    else:
        line = str(l) + '-' + str(l+1)
        stat_lines.append(line)

for i, txt in enumerate(station_list):
    plt.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]), size=15, xytext=(1,5), ha='center', textcoords='offset points', color = "blue")

for i, txt in enumerate(stat_lines):
    plt.annotate(txt, (x[i]+5, y[i]+5), size=10, xytext=(1,5), ha='center', textcoords='offset points')
```

This is the output it gives [image: matplotlib output]

Comment: Your code is not functional. You should post a code that works

Comment: @LaurentB. it works just fine on jupyter notebook?

Comment: I would say with minimum data inside for a quick debugging like one do not have your dataset