# How to plot a circle in python with a contour command, so that i can put clabel on the lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to plot circles on a figure with a radius of each line, exactly like contour plots.
so that i can put plt.clabel(inline=True), and I will get radius on each circle.
Just like in figure2, I want to add labels to each radius in figure1 and that's not possible with plt.plot, so if anyone could please help me.
[image]

[image]

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=[5,5],dpi=100)
t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
plt.plot(0.01*np.cos(t),0.01*np.sin(t),lw=1, color='k')
plt.plot(25*np.cos(t),25*np.sin(t),lw=1, color='k')
plt.plot(50*np.cos(t),50*np.sin(t),lw=1, color='k')
plt.plot(75*np.cos(t),75*np.sin(t),lw=1, color='k')
plt.plot(100*np.cos(t),100*np.sin(t),lw=1, color='k')
plt.plot(125*np.cos(t),125*np.sin(t),lw=1, color='k')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exactly use `plt.clabel`, a possible solution is to construct manually the entries for the contour plot like in the code below (the result is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BFop.png)). Probably this is not the more efficient way to do it but it should do the work at least for drawing circles. For a more elegant way you can refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39402483/16243574.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=[10,5],dpi=100)
t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
ax[0].plot(0.01*np.cos(t),0.01*np.sin(t),lw=1, color='k')
ax[0].plot(25*np.cos(t),25*np.sin(t),lw=1, color='k')
ax[0].plot(50*np.cos(t),50*np.sin(t),lw=1, color='k')
ax[0].plot(75*np.cos(t),75*np.sin(t),lw=1, color='k')
ax[0].plot(100*np.cos(t),100*np.sin(t),lw=1, color='k')
ax[0].plot(125*np.cos(t),125*np.sin(t),lw=1, color='k')

coords = np.ones((len(t),len(t)))*t
Z = np.linspace(0, 130, len(t)*len(t))
Z = Z.reshape((len(t), len(t)))
rad = [0.1, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125]
spacing = [30, 60, 20, 15, 10, 5]
for i in range(len(rad)):
    CS = ax[1].contour(rad[i]*np.cos(coords), rad[i]*np.sin(coords), Z, colors='k', levels=[rad[i]])
    ax[1].clabel(CS, fontsize=10, inline=True, fmt='%.0f', inline_spacing=spacing[i])
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the efficient way to plot..

Comment: In this answer you can find a Github repo for inline labels:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39402483/16243574